# Activate spring profile in case other is not active

Tags: java, spring

In my application based on spring profile rabbitmq or oracle jms queues can be used. Currently one is activated by one profile and the other by second one. But it has it's disadvantage. Namely if you forget to activate on of the profiles application will not work. What I would like to achieve is kind of default profile. So that if no `oracle-jms` profile is active rabbit queues would be used by default. I'm aware that I can use profile negation on beans like that:

```java
@Profile("oracle-jms")
@Configuration
public class OracleJmsConfiguration {
    ...
}

@Profile("!oracle-jms")
@Configuration
public class RabbitMQConfiguration {
    ...
}
```

But although it works for beans it forces me to keep Rabbit configuration properties in main `application.yml` instead of dedicated one like `application-rabbitmq.yml`. I know that Rabbit will be used far more often and keeping its defaults in main file isn't worst option but I'm still wondering whether is it possible to do some trick to activate `rabbitmq` profile when `oracle-jms` is not activated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EnvironmentPostProcessor`

Firstly create class that implements EnvironmentPostProcessor

```
public final class DefaultEnv implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {
    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(final ConfigurableEnvironment environment, final SpringApplication application) {
        final String[] activeProfiles = environment.getActiveProfiles();
        if (activeProfiles.length == 0) {
            environment.setActiveProfiles("rabbitmq");
        }
    }
}
```

Secondly create the following file

```
/resource/META-INF/spring.factories
```

in this file write this line

```
org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor = com.pack.DefaultEnv
```

And that is , before your context will be created , spring will call this DefaultEnv class and will set rabbit environment

Comment: Finally changed one thing (`environment.addActiveProfile("rabbitmq")` instead of `environment.setActiveProfiles("rabbitmq")`) because I have more profiles. Nevertheless it works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`@ConditionalOnMissingBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnMissingBean.html), e.g.

```
@Profile("foo")
@Configuration
public class FooConfiguration {
    ...
}

@Profile("bar")
@Configuration
public class BarConfiguration {
    ...
}

@ConditionalOnMissingBean({FooConfiguration.class, BarConfiguration.class})
@Configuration
public class DefaultConfiguration {
    ...
}
```

Also look at the javadoc of the [`@ConditionalOnMissingBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnMissingBean.html) annotation, for how to use it on a `@Bean` method.

Comment: It requires more code to achieve same things as mine and still I don't see how it helps with separating properties to separate yaml file.

Answer (score 0):

You could add `spring.profiles.active` to application.properties:

```
spring.profiles.active=rabbitmq
```

It will activate 'rabbitmq' profile.

And you can override it by:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=oracle-jms
```

Comment: But which profile will be enabled if I start my apps with -Dspring.profiles.active=dev,postgres? As far as I'm afraid it would work only when no other profiles are used, or am I wrong? In case `rabbitmq` and `oracle-jms` are the only ones it should work fine.